# gsubfn: differences between perl and tclk?

Tags: regex, r

I'm surprised by the difference between these two:

```
strapply(state.name, "^(?:Al|Ma)(.).*(.)$", simplify=rbind, FUN=c, perl=T)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "a"  "a"  ""  
[2,] "a"  "a"  ""  
[3,] "i"  "e"  ""  
[4,] "r"  "d"  ""  
[5,] "s"  "s"  ""  
strapply(state.name, "^(?:Al|Ma)(.).*(.)$", simplify=rbind, FUN=c)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "a"  "a" 
[2,] "a"  "a" 
[3,] "i"  "e" 
[4,] "r"  "d" 
[5,] "s"  "s"
```

Is there an obvious explanation for this?  Clearly not a huge deal, especially since:

```
strapply(state.name, "^(?:Al|Ma)(.).*(.)$", simplify=rbind, FUN=c, perl=T, backref=-2)
```

forces the correct answer, but I'd like to make sure I understand the engine differences.  Presumably this is related to different backreference detection strategies?  From vignette:

> Since gsubfn uses a potentially time consuming trial and error algorithm to automatically determine the number of back references the performance can be sped up somewhat by specifying backref even if all back references are to be passed.

Loosely related, can I generally assume that `tclk` is much faster than `pcre`?  Seems to be from some informal benchmarking.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken when using the `perl = TRUE` flag gsubfn uses the R engine instead of the much faster tcl one (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the `R` engine is used `strapply` figures out where the capture groups are itself.  You can help it along by telling it how many there are as you noticed.  When the tcl engine is used then tcl functions (which are ultimately written in C) locate the capture groups so its different code doing the work accounting for the differences.

Regarding speed `strapplyc` is the fastest function in the package whereas `gsubfn` and `strapply` are slower.  `strapplyc` can be particularly fast on very long strings but for situation where you have to repeatedly go back and forth between R and tcl there would be some overhead in doing so.

For an example of a long string try the one at the end of `?strapplyc` which extracts all words from the James Joyce book Ulysses.  At the time `strapplyc` was written certain alternative approaches not involving the gsubfn package crashed R on my system with that example but `strapplyc` was able to handle it and do so quickly.

If speed is very important note that breaking up strings is expensive so if you can find an approach which does not do that then you can get a speed advantage. For example `gregexpr` just returns positions so it does not actually have to move copies of strings around and I would expect that it would be faster provided your code does not have to subsequently extract the strings in a following step.

Using tcl was just an easy way to leverage existing R facilities to get some speed. To me the main advantage of `gsubfn`, `strapply` and `strapplyc` is that they can be used to more easily express certain manipulations.   The regular expressions involved are sometimes simpler (often not requiring zero length lookahead even when the alterantives do) and `gsubfn` and `strapply` have a richer set of replacement objects (character strings, functions, lists and proto objects).  With proto objects they can maintain state between successive matches (such as replacing the ith match in each string with i).  See the accompanying [vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/vignettes/gsubfn.pdf) and [home page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html) for more.

Comment: Thanks Gabor.  Great package by the way.  I was looking to write a string interpolation function (I didn't know that was the technical term so didn't find anything when I looked) and someone pointed `gsubfn` to me.  I also unfortunately ended up writing a `preg_match_all` function before I was aware of `gsubfn` and in particular `gsubfn::strapply` which does the same thing.  The `fn` stuff is really neat too.

Comment: Incidentally, why don't you use the position info from `gregexpr` to determine the subpattern match location/quantity when using the R Perl engine?  That's what I ended up doing when writing `preg_match_all` (and incidentally, this is how I ran into the discrepancy in the question, by comparing my unit tests with the output of `strapply`).

Comment: When it does not use tcl it uses `gsub` and `strsplit`.  Since a regular expression with lookahead not using gsubfn usually translates into a simpler regular expression without lookahead in gusbfn perl=TRUE is not used that often.